# Сравнить вложенные массивы?

Tags: php

$result = array_diff($array, $array2)  почему такая конструкция перестаёт работать если сделать так
 $array2=array_chunk($array2, 4); $array=array_chunk($array, 4)

и как всё таки сравнить вложенный массив с вложенным массивом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как тебе уже написали, в пхп нет рекурсивной ф-ии array_diff, для сравнения многомерных массивов используй ключи массивов, посмотри на этот пример

```
$array  = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8',];
$array2 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8',];

$result = array_diff($array, $array2);
print_r($result);//пустой массив

//---

$array=array_chunk($array, 4);
$array2=array_chunk($array2, 4);
print_r($array);//двумерный массив
print_r($array2);//двумерный массив

$result = array_diff($array[0], $array2[0]);
print_r($result);//пустой массив

$result = array_diff($array[1], $array2[1]);
print_r($result);//пустой массив
```

Comment: Сравнил одномерные массивы, получил допустим 3 различия ответ в виде массива ключ и значение, т.к в массиве повторяется данные каждые 7 строк упростило реализацию поставленной задачи применить условие

Answer (score 0):

Стандартной функции для этого нет, но есть несколько вариантов

1. Сделать из многомерных массив одномерные и использовать array_diff
2. Использовать array_udiff с callback функцией

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-udiff.php